# How to stack my navbar vertically

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to edit the coding where when the @Media width is less than 600 px, I want  my navigation bar to stack vertically like this[image: this is what i want it to look like.]

So basically I want the nav bar to stack vertically and everything that starts on another section (aka the recent updates section) to fall under one column. The code below is what i've done so far with the html and css.

```css
body{background:#000;font:normal small "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:20px 0;padding:0;}
h1,h2,h3{color:#B13413;}
h2{font-size:1.6em;}
h3{font-size:1em;margin:0;}
p,ul,ol,blockquote{margin-top:0;}
a:link{border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC;text-decoration:none;color:#3284B5;}
#header{width:700px;height:200px;background:url(../img/img1.jpg) no-repeat;margin:0 auto;}
#header *{border:none;text-decoration:none;font-weight:400;color:#FFF;margin:0;}
#header h1{float:left;font-size:3em;padding:140px 0 0 20px;}
#menu{width:700px;height:41px;background:#37AEF2 url(../img/img2.gif);margin:0 auto;}
#menu ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
#menu li{display:inline;}
#menu a{display:block;float:left;height:32px;text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;padding:9px 20px 0;}
#menu a:hover,#menu .active a{background:url(../img/img3.gif);color:#FFF; }
#content{width:700px;background:url(../img/img4.gif);margin:0 auto;}
#colAd{float:left;width:120px;padding:10px;}
#colContent{float:left;width:360px;padding:20px 10px 0;  }
#colSidebar{float:left;width:160px;padding:20px 10px 0;}
#footer{width:700px;background:url(../img/img6.gif) repeat-x;font-size:smaller;margin:0 auto;padding:10px 0;}
#footer *{color:#666;}
a:hover,img{border:none;}
table th, td{
 border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sploosh - You can splash in sploosh!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssmobile/main.css" > 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssmobile/responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <h1><a href="index.html">Splöösh - Mobile</a></h1>
  
</div>
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="2" title="">splöösh Desktop</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="3" title="">My Photos</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="4" title="">My Bookmarks</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Me</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="content">
 <div id="colAd"> <a href="#"><img src="img/ad_120x600.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="600" /></a> </div>
 <div id="colContent">
  <h2> Splöösh!</h2>
  <p><em><strong>Splöösh</strong></em> onec nulla est, laoreet quis, pellentesque in, congue in, dui. Nunc rhoncus placerat augue. Donec justo odio, eleifend varius, volutpat venenatis, sagittis ut, orci. </p>
  <h2>Viewport dimensions:</h2>
  <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><b> Width </b></td>
      <td> <b>Height</b> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> <b>Page</b> </td>
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
       document.write(width); 
       </script></td>
      <td><script type = "text/javascript">
       var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
       document.write(height); 
       </script> </td>
     
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><b> Screen</b> </td>
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var width = window.screen.width;
       document.write(width); 
       </script></td>
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var height = window.screen.height;
       document.write(height); 
       </script></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> <b>ViewPort</b> </td>
      <td><script type = "text/javascript">
       var width = window.innerWidth;
       document.write(width); 
       </script></td>
  
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var height = window.innerHeight;
       document.write(height); </script></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
        <p id="desc"></p> 
        <p>Sed vestibulum blandit nisl. Quisque elementum convallis purus. Quisque pellentesque semper massa:</p>
  <ol>
   <li><a href="#">Suspendisse quis gravida massa felis</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Vivamus sagittis bibendum erat</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Nullam et orci in erat viverra ornare</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Suspendisse quis gravida massa felis</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Curabitur malesuada turpis nec ante</a></li>
  </ol>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolore </h3>
  <p>Aliquam gravida massa eu arcu. Fusce mollis tristique sem. Sed eu eros imperdiet eros interdum blandit. Vivamus sagittis bibendum erat. Curabitur malesuada turpis nec.</p>
  <p><a href="#">Pellentesque sed vestibulum blandit&#8230;</a></p>
 </div>
 
    <div id="colSidebar">
  <h2>Recent Updates</h2>
  <h3>Etiam suscipit et</h3>
  <p>Rhoncus ac, lacinia, nisl. Aliquam gravida massa eu arcu. <a href="#">More&#8230;</a></p>
  <h3>Nunc pellentesque</h3>
  <p>Sed vestibulum blandit nisl. Quisque elementum convallis purus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec nulla est, laoreet quis, pellentesque in. <a href="#">More&#8230;</a></p>
  <h3>Suspendis potenti</h3>
  <p>Donec nulla est, laoreet quis, pellentesque in, congue in, dui. Nunc rhoncus placerat augue. Donec justo odio, eleifend varius, volutpat venenatis, sagittis ut, orci. <a href="#">More&#8230;</a></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="120" /></a></p>
 </div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <p>Copyright splöösh.com Contact Legal Info Site Map Email</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try apply `width: 100%;` and `text-align: center;` on yours `li`s

Comment: I've tried changing it to that but some odd reason nothing changes.

Comment: Your working code is below, Run the snippet and go into full screen, drag your browser to resize to the `600px` and make sure that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `display : block` on your `li` and remove the `float : left` on your `<a>`

Comment: I've tried it but for some odd reason nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove `float: left;` on `<a>`

2) add `display: block;` on `#menu`

3) update height to `height: auto;` on `#menu`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the navigation bar but the h1 title is stuck in the middle of the nav bar. I tried making it display: block but it didn't work.

Comment: where do you want to put the H1?

Comment: above the navbar just like in the picture I showed above. Its in the header image and above the nav bar.

Comment: just put the height to 100px as you want and remove the padding: 140px from the h1.

Comment: Take a look: [https://fiddle.jshell.net/gf4z5tyf/](https://fiddle.jshell.net/gf4z5tyf/)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `@media` property to first define a screen size at which you wish the changes to occur. Then adjust your `<li>`, `<a>` and other divs to the appropriate styling. Code below, be sure to **run the view in full screen** and adjust browser Horizontal Width by dragging to see changes. I'll continue to refine.

```css
body{background:#000;font:normal small "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:20px 0;padding:0;}
h1,h2,h3{color:#B13413;}
h2{font-size:1.6em;}
h3{font-size:1em;margin:0;}
p,ul,ol,blockquote{margin-top:0;}
a:link{border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC;text-decoration:none;color:#3284B5;}
#header{width:700px;height:200px;background:url(../img/img1.jpg) no-repeat;margin:0 auto;}
#header *{border:none;text-decoration:none;font-weight:400;color:#FFF;margin:0;}
#header h1{float:left;font-size:3em;padding:140px 0 0 20px;}
#menu{width:700px;height:41px;background:#37AEF2 url(../img/img2.gif);margin:0 auto;}
#menu ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
#menu li{display:inline;}
#menu a{display:block;float:left;height:32px;text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;padding:9px 20px 0;}
#menu a:hover,#menu .active a{background:url(../img/img3.gif);color:#FFF; }
#content{width:700px;background:url(../img/img4.gif);margin:0 auto;}
#colAd{float:left;width:120px;padding:10px;}
#colContent{float:left;width:360px;padding:20px 10px 0;  }
#colSidebar{float:left;width:160px;padding:20px 10px 0;}
#footer{width:700px;background:url(../img/img6.gif) repeat-x;font-size:smaller;margin:0 auto;padding:10px 0;}
#footer *{color:#666;}
a:hover,img{border:none;}
table th, td{
 border: 1px solid white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  #menu li{
    display: block;
  }
  #menu a {
    float: none;
    
  }
  #content {
    clear: both;
  }
  #menu {
      height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sploosh - You can splash in sploosh!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssmobile/main.css" > 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssmobile/responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <h1><a href="index.html">Splöösh - Mobile</a></h1>
  
</div>
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="2" title="">splöösh Desktop</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="3" title="">My Photos</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="4" title="">My Bookmarks</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Me</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="content">
 <div id="colAd"> <a href="#"><img src="img/ad_120x600.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="600" /></a> </div>
 <div id="colContent">
  <h2> Splöösh!</h2>
  <p><em><strong>Splöösh</strong></em> onec nulla est, laoreet quis, pellentesque in, congue in, dui. Nunc rhoncus placerat augue. Donec justo odio, eleifend varius, volutpat venenatis, sagittis ut, orci. </p>
  <h2>Viewport dimensions:</h2>
  <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><b> Width </b></td>
      <td> <b>Height</b> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> <b>Page</b> </td>
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
       document.write(width); 
       </script></td>
      <td><script type = "text/javascript">
       var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
       document.write(height); 
       </script> </td>
     
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><b> Screen</b> </td>
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var width = window.screen.width;
       document.write(width); 
       </script></td>
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var height = window.screen.height;
       document.write(height); 
       </script></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> <b>ViewPort</b> </td>
      <td><script type = "text/javascript">
       var width = window.innerWidth;
       document.write(width); 
       </script></td>
  
      <td> <script type = "text/javascript">
       var height = window.innerHeight;
       document.write(height); </script></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
        <p id="desc"></p> 
        <p>Sed vestibulum blandit nisl. Quisque elementum convallis purus. Quisque pellentesque semper massa:</p>
  <ol>
   <li><a href="#">Suspendisse quis gravida massa felis</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Vivamus sagittis bibendum erat</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Nullam et orci in erat viverra ornare</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Suspendisse quis gravida massa felis</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Curabitur malesuada turpis nec ante</a></li>
  </ol>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolore </h3>
  <p>Aliquam gravida massa eu arcu. Fusce mollis tristique sem. Sed eu eros imperdiet eros interdum blandit. Vivamus sagittis bibendum erat. Curabitur malesuada turpis nec.</p>
  <p><a href="#">Pellentesque sed vestibulum blandit&#8230;</a></p>
 </div>
 
    <div id="colSidebar">
  <h2>Recent Updates</h2>
  <h3>Etiam suscipit et</h3>
  <p>Rhoncus ac, lacinia, nisl. Aliquam gravida massa eu arcu. <a href="#">More&#8230;</a></p>
  <h3>Nunc pellentesque</h3>
  <p>Sed vestibulum blandit nisl. Quisque elementum convallis purus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec nulla est, laoreet quis, pellentesque in. <a href="#">More&#8230;</a></p>
  <h3>Suspendis potenti</h3>
  <p>Donec nulla est, laoreet quis, pellentesque in, congue in, dui. Nunc rhoncus placerat augue. Donec justo odio, eleifend varius, volutpat venenatis, sagittis ut, orci. <a href="#">More&#8230;</a></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="120" /></a></p>
 </div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <p>Copyright splöösh.com Contact Legal Info Site Map Email</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```